Is Attic Greek grammar completely reconstructed and understood as Latin grammar is?
I am interested in studying Attic Greek and learning it to fluency comparable to what a native speaker of a modern language is capable of, but my friend told me that such a task is impossible since Attic Greek's grammar is not even as well-preserved as that of Latin. My friend noted that the earliest extant Ancient Greek grammar text is Dionysius Thrax's Tékhnē grammatikē, which was written during the period when Koine Greek was in the ascendant and when Attic Greek was no longer spoken as a native language by many people. My friend said that, on the other hand, Latin grammar was documented in greater detail by native speakers in several grammar texts and manuals. Finally, my friend claimed that the Classical Latin text corpus is around 9 million words, while that of Attic Greek is only about 5 million words, giving scholars more material for deciphering Latin than Attic Greek.
Now, I am doubting about how much we can know about Attic Greek grammar; what is the state of the preservation of Attic Greek grammar as compared to Latin grammar? Is a larger portion of Latin grammar better-understood than Attic Greek grammar? Also, is Koine Greek grammar better-preserved and documented in greater detail than Attic Greek grammar?
I am passionate about studying ancient languages, but I also wish to invest time only in languages which I can learn completely and in detail.

The only way to really gain the level of native fluency is total immersion. With whom will you be speaking ancient Greek? Even most "modern Latin-speaking" groups aren't really speaking with native fluency, but learned imitation, often poorly so. Language is so much more than grammar.
